# TopicARN not found when creating ConfigurationSetEventDestination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I have an SNS Topic ARN that I'm trying to programmatically assign as the EventDestination for SES. I'm using a Custom CloudFormation resource and here is the order of my script:

- list the topics currently in sns (validate that the lambda running has access to sns)
- create a configuration set
- create an event destination with topic arn

The Lambda that is executing during CloudFormation has access to list the topic. But when it gets to creating the EventDestination. It cannot find the topic. It throws the following error:

```
2018-02-05T23:42:22.538Z    357e9918-0ace-11e8-a033-b70f6bdba611    { InvalidSNSDestination: Could not access SNS topic <arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:846743712894:REDACTED>.
    at Request.extractError (/var/task/src/sesRuleSet.js:17884:29)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/src/sesRuleSet.js:20237:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/src/sesRuleSet.js:20209:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/src/sesRuleSet.js:30887:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/task/src/sesRuleSet.js:30226:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/src/sesRuleSet.js:31033:12)
    at /var/task/src/sesRuleSet.js:31045:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/src/sesRuleSet.js:30242:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/src/sesRuleSet.js:30889:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/src/sesRuleSet.js:20247:18)
  message: 'Could not access SNS topic <arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:846743712894:REDACTED>.',
  code: 'InvalidSNSDestination',
  time: 2018-02-05T23:42:22.538Z,
  requestId: '363abdd6-0ace-11e8-82ef-3ba09d6eb8e6',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 18.25373598353528 }
```

Here is the code in question:

```
.then(() => {
  console.log('Checking Access to SNS topic');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params: AWS.SNS.ListTopicsInput = {};
    sns.listTopics(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return reject(err);
      }
      console.log(data);
      return resolve();
    });
  });
})
.then(() => {
  console.log('Create Configuration Set');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params: AWS.SES.CreateConfigurationSetRequest = {
      ConfigurationSet: {
        Name: 'configset',
      },
    };
    console.log(params);
    ses.createConfigurationSet(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      console.log(data);
      resolve();
    });
  });
})
.then(() => {
  console.log('Create Configuration Set Event Destination');
  return  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params: AWS.SES.CreateConfigurationSetEventDestinationRequest = {
      ConfigurationSetName: 'configset',
      EventDestination: {
        MatchingEventTypes: ['open', 'click'],
        Name: 'OpenAndClickHandler',
        SNSDestination: {
          TopicARN: `REDACTED`,
        },
      },
    };
    console.log(params);
    ses.createConfigurationSetEventDestination(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the question we need to know to help is.  Can you publish to any SNS topic?  your code looks fine but you might need to add a policy to allow SES to publish to the SNS topic

Comment: The role that is executing the custom cloud formation resource via lambda has permissions via policy to publish to the SNS topic.

Is there something else that needs a custom policy?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. Is your SNS topic well configured?

does your lambda is in the same Region?

Does your lambda has access to create this events in SES ConfigurationSet?